# Clickhouse WATCH query not catching live and window views

Tags: clickhouse

New to Clickhouse and trying to run some examples I found on watch and live views. Testing this locally. I am doing the following:

1. Install and run Clickhouse server

```
    $ curl https://clickhouse.com/ | sh
```

```
    $ ./clickhouse server
```

2. Start 3 Clickhouse client sessions @ `http://127.0.0.1:8123/play`
3. In client1: I create the table and add watch and live views
   Create table

```
 CREATE TABLE data (`id` UInt64, `timestamp` DateTime) ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY tuple();
```

Set experimentation settings

```
set allow_experimental_live_view = 1
set allow_experimental_window_view = 1
```

Create views

```
CREATE WINDOW VIEW ENGINE = Memory wv AS
SELECT
    count(id),
    tumbleStart(w_id) AS window_start
FROM data
GROUP BY tumble(timestamp, toIntervalSecond('10')) AS w_id
```

```
CREATE LIVE VIEW lv AS
SELECT
    count(id),
    toStartOfInterval(timestamp, toIntervalSecond(10)) AS window_start
FROM data
GROUP BY window_start
```

4. In client2:

```
set allow_experimental_window_view = 1
```

```
WATCH wv
```

5. In client3:

```
set allow_experimental_live_view = 1
```

```
WATCH lv
```

6. I then insert data into the table in client1:

```
INSERT INTO data VALUES(1,now())
```

At this point I am expecting client2 and client3 to show up the new insert, but I don't. The watch query keeps running.

[image]

[image]

**Server logs** don't show any errors:

For window:

```
2022.11.18 16:14:27.017578 [ 40370560 ] {} <Trace> DynamicQueryHandler: Request URI: /?session_id=watch1&add_http_cors_header=1&default_format=JSONCompact&max_result_rows=1000&max_result_bytes=10000000&result_overflow_mode=break
2022.11.18 16:14:27.017628 [ 40370560 ] {} <Debug> HTTP-Session: 040b8758-358d-4e1d-9d77-f0a2bc03e16a Authenticating user 'default' from 127.0.0.1:57749
2022.11.18 16:14:27.017663 [ 40370560 ] {} <Debug> HTTP-Session: 040b8758-358d-4e1d-9d77-f0a2bc03e16a Authenticated with global context as user 94309d50-4f52-5250-31bd-74fecac179db
2022.11.18 16:14:27.017679 [ 40370560 ] {} <Debug> HTTP-Session: 040b8758-358d-4e1d-9d77-f0a2bc03e16a Creating named session context with name: watch1, user_id: 94309d50-4f52-5250-31bd-74fecac179db
2022.11.18 16:14:27.017734 [ 40370560 ] {} <Debug> HTTP-Session: 040b8758-358d-4e1d-9d77-f0a2bc03e16a Creating query context from session context, user_id: 94309d50-4f52-5250-31bd-74fecac179db, parent context user: default
2022.11.18 16:14:27.018153 [ 40370560 ] {7e10fe9b-1443-4ac3-947a-e7b458d2db63} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 127.0.0.1:57749) WATCH wv (stage: Complete)
2022.11.18 16:14:27.018343 [ 40370560 ] {7e10fe9b-1443-4ac3-947a-e7b458d2db63} <Trace> ContextAccess (default): Access granted: SELECT(`count(id)`, window_start) ON default.wv
2022.11.18 16:14:38.479779 [ 40370695 ] {} <Debug> DNSResolver: Updating DNS cache
2022.11.18 16:14:38.479952 [ 40370695 ] {} <Debug> DNSResolver: Updated DNS cache
```

For live:

```
2022.11.18 16:11:19.136189 [ 40341193 ] {} <Trace> DynamicQueryHandler: Request URI: /?session_id=live1&add_http_cors_header=1&default_format=JSONCompact&max_result_rows=1000&max_result_bytes=10000000&result_overflow_mode=break
2022.11.18 16:11:19.136243 [ 40341193 ] {} <Debug> HTTP-Session: ed979034-3f3b-4e62-8e64-94b553b6bef1 Authenticating user 'default' from 127.0.0.1:57556
2022.11.18 16:11:19.136286 [ 40341193 ] {} <Debug> HTTP-Session: ed979034-3f3b-4e62-8e64-94b553b6bef1 Authenticated with global context as user 94309d50-4f52-5250-31bd-74fecac179db
2022.11.18 16:11:19.136309 [ 40341193 ] {} <Debug> HTTP-Session: ed979034-3f3b-4e62-8e64-94b553b6bef1 Creating named session context with name: live1, user_id: 94309d50-4f52-5250-31bd-74fecac179db
2022.11.18 16:11:19.136346 [ 40341193 ] {} <Debug> HTTP-Session: ed979034-3f3b-4e62-8e64-94b553b6bef1 Creating query context from session context, user_id: 94309d50-4f52-5250-31bd-74fecac179db, parent context user: default
2022.11.18 16:11:19.136753 [ 40341193 ] {f379adf3-196a-45d3-8e64-d2f9e5401f9e} <Debug> executeQuery: (from 127.0.0.1:57556) WATCH lv (stage: Complete)
2022.11.18 16:11:19.136945 [ 40341193 ] {f379adf3-196a-45d3-8e64-d2f9e5401f9e} <Trace> ContextAccess (default): Access granted: SELECT(`count(id)`, window_start) ON default.lv
```

Any idea what I maybe doing wrong or missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Live View nor the Watch issue. Read the documentation carefully:

> The **JSONEachRowWithProgress** format should be used when watching LIVE
> VIEW tables over the HTTP interface. The progress messages will be
> added to the output to keep the long-lived HTTP connection alive until
> the query result changes. The interval between progress messages is
> controlled using the live_view_heartbeat_interval setting.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but I tried this too. I set output_format_json_array_of_rows=1 and live_view_heartbeat_interval=1 but same result, the WATCH query gets stuck.

Comment: Can you connect through `clickhouse-client` and try to `WATCH` from it?

Comment: I tried that and it works. But now using the language client (Node.js) leads to the same situation and is stuck.